# perspective / backface-visibility causing causing element to disappear

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, nib, stylus

I'm using backface-visibility, perspective, and transform to create a card-flipping effect.

These are the styles:

```
 .org
    perspective 1000
    position relative
    .orgInfo
      transform-style preserve-3d
      backface-visibility hidden
    &:hover .orgInfo
      transform: rotateY( 180deg )
```

This is the markup:

```
<div class="org">
  <div class="orgInfo">
    <img src="assets/images/designhack.svg" alt="Design &amp; Hack" class="logo full">
    <div class="description">
      {{CONTENTS}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when you hover over a card, one or two of the other cards disappear. Check it out at http://joelcalifa.com (the colored boxes).

For some reason this seems to be happening on my new macbook but not on my previous non-Retina macbook. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Firefox and it looks beautiful to me :) 
 
Chrome does the disappearing thing though. Also IE has the flipping effect, but without the 'flipped' side of the card showing up

Comment: Are you using some sort of repeat thing to dynamically place the cards, or are they all separate html?

Comment: Is this Sass or Stylus?  It can't be both.  Did you try looking at the compiled CSS to see if it is generating the expected results (if the compilation is correct, then just post the compiled CSS)?  There's more than one browser/version that runs on "macbook", which one are you using?

Comment: Does removing `-webkit-perspective` make a difference? I remove it when inspecting the element in Chrome and the flickering stops.